# Android receiving number, email, etc. from contact

Tags: android, contacts

I want to access different contact information like a number, an email etc.
I use code from official Android documentation:

```
static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;  // The request code

private void pickContact() {
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// Check which request it is that we're responding to
if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
    // Make sure the request was successful
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Get the URI that points to the selected contact
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();

        String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column
        int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
        String number = cursor.getString(column);

        // Do something with the phone number...
    }
}
}
```

The problem is, I can only access phone number and name, other data not. I can change pickContactIntent.setType to Email content type, but that I can access only Email... How can I access different kind of data in this case ?

Comment: read `ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY` documentation

Comment: CONTENT_DIRECTORY

Added in API level 5
String CONTENT_DIRECTORY
The directory twig for this sub-table

Constant Value: "data"

Comment: The statement above is everything I found about it.

Comment: so read class documentation

Comment: I read the class documentation, googled the topic but couldn't find the answer. Will you now write that I should buy a book or perhaps tell me something, which might really help me ?

Comment: no, no book needed, it states: `"A sub-directory of a single contact that contains all of the constituent raw contact ContactsContract.Data rows."`, so simply append `Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY` to a particular contact `Uri` to get sub-directory with all the contact's data

Comment: Thanks for a hint, however contactUri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY) doesn't work in my example ("cannot resolve CONTENT_DIRECTORY")

Comment: what is `"cannot resolve CONTENT_DIRECTORY"`? is it a runtime error? if so what is a stack trace?

Comment: The line Uri contactUri = data.getData(); content://com.android.contacts/data/6

Comment: cant edit comment sorry, 
the line Uri contactUri = data.getData() 
returns for example 
content://com.android.contacts/data/6
probably the problem is I can't append to it

Comment: what is a stack trace then? what runtime error do you have?

Comment: ok i put it, but why does the code:
contactUri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
            String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
gives me a phone number not an email ???

Comment: ok try this: http://pastebin.com/be8RPCAN, if you want to see all the data pass `null` instead of `projection`

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI: content://com.android.contacts/data/1/data

Comment: see the comment in my code

Comment: thanks, it works,but the result is in command line in a weird form, how to build a string with it ?

Comment: what command line?

Comment: oops, I meant an android monitor. Result is in form:
 0 { data1=xxx } 
1 {data1=yyy} 
I would like to have it like: xxx, yyy
when I use StringBuilder as a parameter for dumb_cursor

Comment: just use Cursor API: moveTo*(), get*() etc

Comment: Thank you very, very much !! How I can I accept the answer written in comment ?