# Android get all details of a contact

Tags: android

I didn't find any solution in the Internet, only a tutorial on Android Developers, which unfortunately gives only a small part of code needed for it. I ended up having something like this:

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Data;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

// Defines the selection clause
private static final String SELECTION = Data.LOOKUP_KEY + " = ?"; // Defines the array to hold the search criteria
private String[] mSelectionArgs = { "" };
private String mLookupKey;
private static final String SORT_ORDER = Data.MIMETYPE;
final int DETAILS_QUERY_ID = 0;

private static final String PROJECTION[] = {
        Data._ID, Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DATA1, Data.DATA2, Data.DATA3, Data.DATA4, Data.DATA5, Data.DATA6, Data.DATA7, Data.DATA8, Data.DATA9, Data.DATA10, Data.DATA11, Data.DATA12, Data.DATA13, Data.DATA14, Data.DATA15
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//        getLoaderManager().initLoader(DETAILS_QUERY_ID, null, this);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {
    switch (loaderId) {
        case DETAILS_QUERY_ID:
            // Assigns the selection parameter
             mSelectionArgs[0] = mLookupKey; // Starts the query
            CursorLoader mLoader = new CursorLoader(this, Data.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION,
                    SELECTION, mSelectionArgs, SORT_ORDER);


    }
    return null; // TODO what should be here ?
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
//        switch (loader.getId()) {
//            case DETAILS_QUERY_ID:
//        }
//        break;
//    }
}
}
```

How can I make it work ? https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-details.html is really lacking some code and explanation

Comment: All code parts on that page belong together. Additionally there is a big button to the right "DOWNLAOD THE SAMPLE". Therefore the page does not lack code.

Comment: Robert, did you open that sample ? It does not receive all contact details, only photo, name and mail.

Comment: read `ContactsContract.Contacts.Data` documentation

Comment: I am able to receive all contact data using different code, where I just query using  String[] projection = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA1
        };
The problem is, I need to map data (key-values) and after such a query all the values are listed as data1 like 0 { data1=04343 343 2 } 1{data1=marc} etc
Thats why I tried another solution

Comment: btw you got the answer for your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197756/android-receiving-number-email-etc-from-contact, so what is that question about?

Comment: hi, the question I stated there was in fact about getting all details for a contact and the answer works (thx one more time), but  I noticed two problems:
1) Due to documentation, query should be done in background thread

Comment: 2) I am not able to get Information of a type of received value (for example that 435234234 would be a phone number and test@test.com an email), it seems all is stated as "data1"

Comment: ad 1) use loaders framework, ad 2) see [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds,*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.html) classes